# What's the idiomatic way to batch update a data frame using a custom mapping?

Tags: r

I have a data frame that looks as follows:

```
test <- data.frame(x=c('a','b','a','c','a','b','d'),y=rep('test',7),stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
test
  x    y
1 a test
2 b test
3 a test
4 c test
5 a test
6 b test
7 d test
```

Now I'd like to define a mapping like e.g.

```
mapping <- list(a=1,b=2,c=3,d=4)
mapping
$a
[1] 1
$b
[1] 2
$c
[1] 3
$d
[1] 4
```

and what I want is to batch update my data frame creating a new variable `z` so that wherever an 'a' is found the variable `z` is set to the value 1 according to the mapping (the mapping can be defined in any other way if simpler or better for a possible solution).

My end result should be:

```
  x    y  z
1 a test  1 
2 b test  2 
3 a test  1
4 c test  3
5 a test  1
6 b test  2
7 d test  4
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We can use `stack` with `merge`

```
merge(test, stack(mapping), by.x = 'x', by.y = 'ind')
```

---

It is better to have a named `vector` for mapping directly.  In this case, we `unlist` the `list` to `vector` and use that to match the values in 'x'

```
test$z <- unlist(mapping)[test$x]
```

Comment: @GiovanniAzua  Updated that